# Equality of two complex expressions for $\log\dfrac{1+iz}{1-iz}$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

I am considering the complex expression:

$w=\log\dfrac{1+iz}{1-iz}$

where $z=x+iy$
On substitution $z=x+iy$ in above expression, I got:

$w=\log\dfrac{1+i(x+iy)}{1-i(x+iy)}$

$=\log\dfrac{(1-y)+ix}{(1+y)-ix}........(*)$

Now there are two ways in which one can proceed. For first one I attempted the following:

$w=\log((1-y)+ix)-\log((1+y)-ix))$

Now using the identity $\log(x+iy)= \log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})+i\tan^{-1}\dfrac{y}{x}$

Next,

$w=\dfrac{1}{2}(\log((1-y)^2+x^2)-\log((1+y)^2+x^2)))+i(\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x}{1-y}-\tan^{-1}\dfrac{-x}{1+y})$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}(\log\dfrac{(1-y)^2+x^2}{(1+y)^2+x^2})+i\tan^{-1}(\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2-y^2}). ..........(1)$

For the second way, I rationalized the denominator of expression given by $...(*)$ and got the following:

$w=\log\dfrac{(1-y)+ix}{(1+y)-ix}*\dfrac{(1+y)+ix}{(1+y)+ix}$

$=\log\dfrac{(1-x^2-y^2)+i(2x)}{(1+y)^2+x^2}$

$=\log\dfrac{\sqrt{(1-x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2}}{(1+y)^2+x^2}+i\tan^{-1}\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2-y^2}.......(2)$

The two expressions given by equations $....(1)$ and $...(2)$ must be equal but they are not. Their real parts do not match. Why are the two expressions not equal?

Comment: "*Why are the two expressions not equal*" $\;-\;$ Why do you think they are not equal? They actually are.

Comment: @dxiv You are correct.  I was stumped by factor $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z\ne \pm i,$ \begin{align}
& \frac12\log\frac{(1-y)^2+x^2}{(1+y)^2+x^2} = \log\frac{\sqrt{(1-x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2}}{(1+y)^2+x^2}
\\\iff{}& \sqrt{\frac{(1-y)^2+x^2}{(1+y)^2+x^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{(1-x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2}}{(1+y)^2+x^2}
\\\iff{}& \sqrt{(1-y)^2+x^2}\;\left((1+y)^2+x^2\right)  = \sqrt{(1+y)^2+x^2}\sqrt{(1-x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2}
\\\iff{}& \left((1-y)^2+x^2\right)\; \left((1+y)^2+x^2\right)^2 = \left((1+y)^2+x^2\right)\;\left((1-x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2\right)
\\\iff{}& \text{True}.
\end{align}

Btw,

> using the identity $\log(x+iy)= \log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})+i\tan^{-1}\dfrac{y}{x}$

is false: \begin{align}\operatorname{Log}(-1-i)-\operatorname{Log}\sqrt{(-1)^2+(-1)^2} &=-\dfrac{3\pi}4 i\\&\ne i\arctan\dfrac{-1}{-1}.\end{align}